# boolean JSON parameter is false after using default ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, eclipse, boolean, objectmapper

I have JSON response with boolean (isBlocked) parameter

```
{"isBlocked":true,"responseId":"ab123456789", "other":"irrelevant"}
```

My ResponseVO (with auto generated getters and setters using Eclipse):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseVO {

private boolean isBlocked;
private String responseId;
public boolean isBlocked() {
    return isBlocked;
}
public void setBlocked(boolean isBlocked) {
    this.isBlocked = isBlocked;
}
public String getResponseId() {
    return responseId;
}
public void setResponseId(String responseId) {
    this.responseId = responseId;
}
```

}

I'm using `ObjectMapper` to set VO object

```
ResponseVO responseVO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, ResponseVO.class);
```

But boolean parameter is set to false instead of true

```
logger.debug("SpelPaus Block=" + responseVO.isBlocked());
```

Comment: Your JSON should have a property named "blocked", not "isBlocked". Or you should hasve a JsonProperty annotation telling Jackson to use "isBlocked" instead of "blocked".

Comment: Before I'll try it locally I would assume that your naming is off. I guess it should be `setIsBlocked` and `isIsBlocked`, because the name of the field contains `is`. You could use that `@JsonProperty` annotation to set the name of the JSON prop. // edit: yes, renaming the getter and setter or adding `@JsonProperty("isBlocked")` to the field works.

Comment: @Tom adding JsonProperty worked, but the getter/setter are auto generated, is it eclipse issue also?

Comment: This is no issue with Eclipse. The issue is the bad naming in the JSON (like JB Nizet explained) and that the ObjectMapper might look for the getter and setter (when there is no matching method with the appropriate annotation `@JsonGetter` or `@JsonSetter`) using reflection and the raw field name with appended `get`/`is` and `set` to that name

Comment: @Tom I can't blame it as *bad naming* because it's a third party response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the private attribute to `private boolean blocked;`

and setter-getter as

```
public boolean isBlocked()
    {return blocked;}

public void setBlocked(boolean blocked)
    {this.blocked = blocked;}
```

Comment: Need to add also `@JsonProperty("isBlocked")`