# Rest Get method return incorect element name

Tags: java, rest, postman, lombok

I have a problem with My get method in my restfull web service metgod. I create a controller for My User entity, and I have a variable isActive(boolean):
isActive is a name and in all My code I don't have a simple active word, but when I use postman they return me:

```
  {
        "userId": 5,
        "emailLogin": "t5.email@be-tse.com",
        "firstName": "Name_5",
        "lastName": "Lastname_5",
        "userDepartment": "SALESFORCE",
        "roles": [],
        "active": false
    }
```

Last element should be isActive - why it was change? I use lombok it can be a reason?

My entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emailLogin;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private boolean isActive;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserDepartment userDepartment;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

    public User(String emailLogin, String firstName, String lastName, String password, boolean isActive, UserDepartment userDepartment, Set<UserRole> roles) {
        this.emailLogin = emailLogin;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.userDepartment = userDepartment;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Comment: show `isActive` in object, what are the getter/setter?

Comment: I use lombok so I don't have setter/getter

Comment: You might find it confusing, but standard `getter/setter` for boolean `isActive` and `active` are same , i.e `getter isActive()` and `setter setActive(boolean isActive)` `.

Comment: Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593559/boolean-json-parameter-is-false-after-using-default-objectmapper

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an exact field name

```
@JsonProperty("isActive")
public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}
```

Comment: It should also work without manually defining the getter, just by placing `@JsonProperty("isActive")` on the field.